# How to prevent clothes from shrinking in the washing machine

Tags: cleaning, clothing

At the first washing, some clothes shrink. What should I do before washing them in the washing machine to avoid shrinking them?

Comment: Most of the cases I've experienced it was the dryer stage that shrunk my clothing, when I started avoiding the dryer for some of my clothes I was able to avoid the shrinkage

Comment: At the first washing, some clothes shrink. WHAT are those clothes? What materials are you talking about? Do you use hot, warm, or cold water? You need to provide a more detailed question along with some alternatives you have considered or tried that did not work and why you think it could have worked. More detail would be helpful to work on your question. Did you consider what Just Do It suggested?

Comment: As everyone says, in my experience, dryers are the ultimate clothes shrinkers! Hang-drying your clothes should alleviate the shrinking problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of clothes and how did you wash them, but generally I would say :

- Don't use dryer
- Use low temperature (30°C)

Answer (score 0):

The tags on your clothing give instructions on how to wash them. Here is a helpful [reference image](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/icon-set-laundry-symbols-vector-illustration-34266160.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, natural fibers, such as cotton and wool, tend to shrink, industrial ones don't.

- Go one size up when you buy cloths which are made out of cotton or wool, or a material mix with a high percentage of natural fibers.

If you have the problem with cloths at home and you can't exchenage them for bigger ones at the store:

- Don't use a dryer but a drying rack AND
- stretch the cloths by hand while they are wet.

However, this will only help til the next wash.